# How to write commands in filezilla using ssh OR using it with putty

Tags: php, ssh, ftp, putty, filezilla

I need to write a command:

```
su -
```

and get root access, but I don't know where or how to write commands in filezilla program, is there anyway to write that command using PUTTY, and then using filezilla make file edit?

Comment: There's never a reason todo so, what are you trying to achieve? Is it to fix permissions on your uploads?

Comment: @LozCherone yes because I can't edit files and make changes until I get a super user access(root), how do I get it in filezilla?

Answer (score 0):

Connect with putty.

do `su`

then use vi/nano or any other editor to edit the file.

`vi filename` / `nano filename`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fix your uploaded file permissions:

Login to SSH

Add yourself to www-data group

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data "$USER"
```

Then change the owner of the files to that user:

** Correct previously created files: **

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data /var/www
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
```

Now when you upload you wont have issues. Dont use root to do your uploads, create a new user that is part of the www-data group.